# Escaping "quot" using xslt 1.0 from HTML attribute

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have HTML tag as below:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="englishLongDesc" value ="Box height is 5.0 mm (2.9"/74mm length) used for packing"/>
```

I have used XSLT 1.0 as shown below to fetch its value:

```
<content name="Box Description" >
          <xsl:value-of select="./input[@name='englishLongDesc']/@value" />
</content>
```

I am getting answer  ***Box height is 5.0 mm (2.9***

because there is "(quot) in between.

**Question**: I cant change HTML value but can I fetch complete value (i.e. *Box height is 5.0 mm (2.9"/74mm length) used for packing* ) through XSLT 1.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No*, because the XSLT code is doing the 'right' thing. It's the HTML which is broken.

This:

```
<input type="hidden" name="englishLongDesc" value ="Box height is 5.0 mm (2.9"/74mm length) used for packing"/>
```

Is broken HTML. The content of the value attribute really is:

```
Box height is 5.0 mm (2.9
```

And this bit is just garbage:

```
/74mm length) used for packing"
```

[*] Because this is garbage tag soup, it's likely that the DOM model still contains a stray text() node somewhere. By analysing the DOM model itself (write an XSLT stylesheet which does that), you might be able to figure out an additional expression to grab the trailing bit and use concatenation to paper over the problem.

Comment: So, there is no any way to fetch it completely?

Comment: Well not directly. It will depend on how well the parser copes with tag soup and what DOM structure it generates. Because XSLT operates on the DOM/XPath model of the document you are entirely reliant in whatever 'graceful' degradation your parser can provide.

Comment: The best solution is to edit the HTML to be actually HTML, yes. I.e. to fix the problem by properly escaping output.